# What does maxMintAmount mean?

Tags: mint

I'm a newbie here, and this may be a silly question. What does `maxMintAmount` mean in `uint256 public maxMintAmount = 2;` ? Does it mean each NFT can sell up to 2 buyers, or each NFT can sell up to 2 ETH, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on the context - can't say for sure without seeing the code.

But based on the variable name, my guess is that only two unique NFTs can be minted from that contract. So the NFT contract only holds two NFTs which can be minted - no more can be minted.

A single NFT contract often allows minting multiple NFTs, which probably have different properties.

Comment: I'm learning the Remix Ethereum by HashLips NFT. You can see the code on his YouTube video (https://youtu.be/3jizwk6_m1s?t=1372) at 22:52 . I believe what you said is correct.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. Is it 2 NFTs can be minted per NFT, or 2 NFTs can be minted out of the whole collection?

Comment: Most likely per contract. A collection can either include one contract or multiple contracts.